# Latex how to add space between table border and figure inside cell?

Tags: latex, border, margin, figure

I prepared table with images, and I want the images to have space between the line and them inside the table.
How to do it in latex?

The code is here:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\includegraphics[height=2.5cm]{example-image-b} &
\includegraphics[height=2.5cm]{example-image-b} &
\includegraphics[height=2.5cm]{example-image-b} \\ \hline
\textbf{(a)}  & \textbf{(b)} & \textbf{(c)} \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}

\caption{ \textbf{(a)} Some text
\textbf{(b)} Some text
\textbf{(c)} Some text
}
\label{fig:Name}
\extralabel{fig:Name:a}{(a)}
\extralabel{fig:Name:b}{(b)}
\extralabel{fig:Name:c}{(c)}
\end{figure}
```

Image is below:
[image]

I want the images to have a space with the upper line of table, as shown in the image below:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

After some research, I came up to sort of a solution. First, define a new command for the specified height of the cell, which should be greater than the default height of the image:

```
\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.6cm}}
```

Then insert this after the last cell image:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\includegraphics[height=2.5cm]{example-image-b} &
\includegraphics[height=2.5cm]{example-image-b} &
\includegraphics[height=2.5cm]{example-image-b}\Tstrut \\ \hline
\textbf{(a)}  & \textbf{(b)} & \textbf{(c)} \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}

\caption{ \textbf{(a)} Some text
\textbf{(b)} Some text
\textbf{(c)} Some text
}
\label{fig:Name}
\extralabel{fig:Name:a}{(a)}
\extralabel{fig:Name:b}{(b)}
\extralabel{fig:Name:c}{(c)}
\end{figure}
```

See the image:

[image]